# How to get the hierarchy of register in register map by using the field name in sequence

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I've a requirement where I need to re-use my sequence to write register present in different register map, the register name and structure(bit width, field endiness etc) differ in each map but the field name is same. Is there a way, where I can use the field name(string) to get register name or hierarchy in the register map.

Comment: This sounds like a trivial object-oriented task. However, it is difficult to answer your question without more information. you need to provide more explanation and code samples.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that gets a register name given a field name:

```
uvm_field field;
uvm_reg parent_reg;
string parent_reg_name;

field = m_env.m_serial_regmodel.get_field_by_name("TX_DMA_RUN");
parent_reg = field.get_parent;
parent_reg_name = parent_reg.get_name;

// etc
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew, just what I was looking for :)